# Adding placemark to a map using jsp

Tags: jsp, gwt, tomcat

IS it feasible to use gwt-maps-1.1.0.jar package to add a placemark in a map using jsp and tomcat? Or is there any other way to do so??

Answer (score 1):

If your application is not written in GWT (it sounds like this is the case) then you cannot use the gwt-maps library to manipulate Google Maps. gwt-maps will only run on the client (in the browser) in the context of a GWT application.